# Need to run PlugInstall on each open

Tags: vimrc, gvim

I have a `.gvimrc` file created to configure `MacVim`. I'm using `Plug` for package management.

My `.gvimrc` looks as follows:

```
call plug#begin()

Plug 'tpope/vim-sensible' " sensible defaults
Plug 'joshdick/onedark.vim'
Plug 'sheerun/vim-polyglot' " syntax highlight
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree', { 'on':  'NERDTreeToggle' }
Plug 'Xuyuanp/nerdtree-git-plugin'
Plug 'airblade/vim-gitgutter'
Plug '/usr/local/opt/fzf'
Plug 'junegunn/fzf.vim' " fuzzy search
Plug 'w0rp/ale' " linting
Plug 'itmammoth/run-rspec.vim'
Plug 'tpope/vim-rails'
Plug 'itchyny/lightline.vim' 
Plug 'terryma/vim-multiple-cursors' " cmd + d
Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plug 'slim-template/vim-slim'
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdcommenter'
Plug 'sgur/vim-editorconfig'
Plug 'tpope/vim-endwise'
Plug 'ervandew/supertab'

call plug#end()

"""""""""""""
" Settings
"

syntax on
colorscheme onedark

" Font settings
set guifont=Monaco:h13
set linespace=2

set number " display line numbers

set cursorcolumn " display vertical cursor line
set cursorline " display horizontal cursor line

" More natural split direction
set splitright

" Disable scrolls
set guioptions=

" Needed by nerdcommenter
filetype plugin on

" NERDTree options
let NERDTreeMinimalUI = 1
let NERDTreeDirArrows = 1

""""""""""""""
" Key bindings

" Spec runner
map <Leader>t :RunSpec<CR>
map <Leader>tl :RunSpecLine<CR>

" NERDtree
map <Leader>nt :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
map <D-\> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>

" Fuzzy search (FZF)
macmenu File.Print key=<nop>
map <Leader>p :FZF<CR>
nmap <A-p> :FZF<CR>
map <D-p> :FZF<CR>
```

And the thing is - i need to run `PlugInstall` after each editor open as running `:FZF` without it throws `Not an editor command: FZF`. Running `PlugInstall` fixes it till i close the editor. This issue applies **only** to `fzf`, no any other plugin behaves like that.

**edit:** it applies to run-rspec as well

Comment: When you run `:PlugInstall` what does the buffer shows? Does the repo gets cloned again each time? Have you looked at your `~/.vim` and `~/.vim/plugged` directories to see if there is no problem with the permissions? Did you check that the fzf plugin directory exists before you start vim? Did you check that it stills exists after you quit vim? Did you check that you don't have something in your `.vimrc` which is sourced before `.gvimrc` and which might create a conflict?

Comment: Also I just noticed that you don't specify a directory for `plug#begin()`. If you read [the README](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug#usage) you'll see that you are supposed to give a parameter to this function and I'm not sure the behavior is defined without this argument. **Edit** Actually [this should not be a problem](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/blob/master/plug.vim#L119-L121) but you might still want to check that you don't get an error message.

Comment: please try with a `.vimrc` instead.

Comment: What does your vimrc look like? Is it empy?

Comment: Please read https://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#load-plugins: In step (4) basically  `:runtime! plugin/**/*.vim` happens which is before your gvimrc is sourced (step (8)) and `rtp` has been changed by `vim-plug`. You can remove the error by appending to your gvimrc `runtime! plugin/**/*.vim`. However, I recommend to use vimrc and stick to the given source order by vim itself.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers! It turned out putting plug-related stuff to `.vimrc` solved the issue so feel free to post it as an answear and i'm gonna mark it as a solution :)

Answer (score 1):

From [Hotschke in the comments](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/18195/need-to-run-pluginstall-on-each-open#comment31342_18195):

> Please read [`:help load-plugins`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#load-plugins): In step (4) basically `:runtime! plugin/**/*.vim` happens which is before your gvimrc is sourced (step (8)) and `runtimepath` has been changed by vim-plug. You can remove the error by appending to your gvimrc `runtime! plugin/**/*.vim`. However, I recommend to use vimrc and stick to the given source order by vim itself

And [OP's follow-up](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/18195/need-to-run-pluginstall-on-each-open#comment31343_18195):

> It turned out putting plug-related stuff to .vimrc solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a good idea -- I think it is better to find out root cause of the problem.

Anyway to run a command after vim has started you can use autocommands:

```
autocmd VimEnter * PlugInstall
```

I don't know if `PlugInstall` is a command or a function. If it is a function then you should use `call PlugInstall()`

I would also suggest to move all your settings to .vimrc instead of .gvimrc. At least everything that is non-gui related, like all plugs and sets.